# Type checking components

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template, transclusion

I want to pass a component class as input to another component:

```ts
@Component({selector: 'dummy-comp', template:'i am dummy'});
class Dummy {}

@Component({
  selector: 'not-so-dummy',
  template:'<ng-content *ngComponentOutlet="transcluded"></ng-content>'
})
class LessDummy {
  @Input() transcluded: ???
}
```

What type should I use for transcluded? Dummy doesn't extend anything, instead it is using the `@Component` decorator. On the other hand there **is** a Component type, that extends from Directive... Here is some added testing:

```ts
let dummy = Dummy, component = Component;
typeof dummy // "function"
dummy.name // "Dummy"
typeof component // "function"
component.name // "DecoratorFactory"
dummy instanceof component // false
```

If I understand correctly I can use `Function` as type for my `transcluded` input but ideally I'd like to narrow it down. Perhaps I'm going about this the wrong way but here is what I'm trying to achieve:

```ts
<div [ngSwitch]="getTypeOf(input)">
  <div *ngSwitchCase="'Component?'">
    <ng-content *ngComponentOutlet="input"></ng-content>
  </div>
  <span *ngSwitchCase="'string'">{{input}}</span>
  <span *ngSwitchCase="'function'">{{input()}}</span>
</div>
```

I'm at a total loss as to what logic to put it my `getTypeOf` function.

**edit**:
according to [this website](http://blog.wolksoftware.com/decorators-metadata-reflection-in-typescript-from-novice-to-expert-part-ii):

> The prototype of the original constructor is copied to the prototype of f to ensure that the instanceof operator works as expected when we create a new instance of Person.

That would explain why `instanceof` doesn't work.

**edit2**:
some luck with `Reflect`:

```ts
 Reflect.getMetadata('annotations',dummy)[0].selector // "dummy-comp"
```

Comment: is `instanceof` what you are looking for? MDN [instanceof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof)

Comment: can you use a function that test all the possibilities with instanceof? So you pass in the component and `if(input instanceof comp1)` and so on. Then return a string to switch on in the front end?

Comment: in this case I'm not passing an instance but a class, so the class' type is Function as it should

Comment: all the typescript typing goes away once you're in the browser, this likely isn't going to be doable unless you can come up with some reliable way of duck typing a component. or you can just assume if it isn't a function or string then its a component, but that's ugly. Another option is to make separate inputs for string, function and component, and just use the correct one.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are doing transclusion this way? Would [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/YRYGxpOVfXGMjl3VzD3h) work?

Comment: @spectacularbob see the 3rd code sample where I explain what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: @bryan60 the problem here is that I want either a Component class or a simple function that outputs a string. There is no way to differentiate.

Comment: That's the point I was making, they're the same once you're in the browser, hence the need to find a way to ducktype, or just use separate inputs ie @Input() transcludeComponent and @Input() transclude and then you just check which one you're using first.

Comment: @bryan60 it would be possible using `instanceof ` or `isPrototypeOf` if Dummy extended Component directly but I'm new to that decorator business.. just digging for ideas, perhaps using `Reflect` or somesuch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is working:

```
private getTypeOf(d:any): string {
  let type:string = typeof d;
  if (type === 'function') {
    let metaKeys:string = Reflect.getMetadataKeys(d);
    if (metaKeys.indexOf('annotations') > 0) {
      let annotations:string[] = Reflect.getMetadata('annotations', d);
      if (annotations.indexOf('@Component') > 0) {
        type = '@Component';
      }
    }
  }
  return type;
}
```

For more details looks at the [Reflect documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect).

Note that doesn't work on Internet Explorer.

**edit** the `metadata` methods documentation mysterioudly disappeared from MDN website overnight, you can have a look at [this website](https://rbuckton.github.io/reflect-metadata/) instead